# I want to override product view phtml page , I read all solution on stackoverflow and somewhere , no changes or override found

Tags: magento

I  have copy  addtocard.phtml file from vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view  into 
 app\design\frontend\Mytheme\DreamShop\Magento-catalog\templates\product\view and do some changes and then run clean and flush . still not override..... please tell me where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

File path should be: app/design/frontend/Mytheme/DreamShop/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

You can see the module name on file *vendor/magento/module-catalog/registration.php*

Comment: thank you!  yeah I found it in registration.php file